# Systemd service not updating

Tags: python-3, bash, systemd, systemd-startup

I have a service on my Raspberry Pi which runs a bash file on boot. I recently updated the bash file (`run.sh`) but the service is not reflecting the update.

So far I have tried:

- `sudo systemctl disable/enable garden-zero.service`
- `sudo systemtl stop/start garden-zero.service`
- `sudo systemctl daemon-reload`

Nothing has worked. The service is still not running the environment.py script I added.

**Bash File (run.sh)**

```
#!/bin/sh

# Sensors
/home/pi/apps/garden-zero/sensors/environment.py &
/home/pi/apps/garden-zero/sensors/soil-temperature.py &
/home/pi/apps/garden-zero/sensors/soil-moisture.py &

# Metrics
/home/pi/apps/garden-zero/metrics/heartbeat.py &
```

**Service Config**

```
[Unit]
Description=Garden Zero
After=network-online.target

[Service]
Type=forking
ExecStart=run.sh
WorkingDirectory=/home/pi/apps/garden-zero
StandardOutput=inherit
StandardError=inherit
Restart=always
User=gardenAdmin

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**Output** when status is run

```
 garden-zero.service - Garden Zero
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/garden-zero.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2021-06-03 02:40:11 BST; 1h 23min ago
    Tasks: 7 (limit: 725)
   CGroup: /system.slice/garden-zero.service
           ├─406 python3 /home/pi/apps/garden-zero/sensors/soil-temperature.py
           ├─407 python3 /home/pi/apps/garden-zero/sensors/soil-moisture.py
           └─408 python3 /home/pi/apps/garden-zero/metrics/heartbeat.py

Jun 03 02:40:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Garden Zero...
Jun 03 02:40:11 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Garden Zero.

I would expect to see /home/pi/apps/garden-zero/sensors/environment.py listed but its not
```

Comment: You should include some kind of logging in your code if you are running it in the background otherwise everything that happens with it will remain a mystery to you.

Answer (score 2):

The systemd WorkingDirectory= setting defines on which directory the service will be launched, same as when you use cd to change a directory when you're working in the shell.

That doesn't mean that all the other paths (including that from ExecStart=) will now be relative to it, so you still need to fully specify the path to your script in that directive:

```
ExecStart=/home/pi/apps/garden-zero/run.sh
```